# Can't seem to integrate spring-cloud-sleuth into spring boot application

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

Appreciate if someone can provide ideas on how to debug this....

I am trying to integrate spring cloud sleuth with zipkin into one of our microservice. I have the following in the pom.xml and in properties with debug. There are none of the usual messages from spring-cloud-sleuth or spring-cloud-sleuth zipkin in the log. Almost as if spring-cloud-sleuth has not been loaded or started. However I am getting the following debug message:

2021-06-24 13:38:39 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.zipkin2.ZipkinAutoConfiguration$DefaultEndpointLocatorConfiguration': no URL paths identified
2021-06-24 13:38:39 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'zipkinEndpointLocator': no URL paths identified
2021-06-24 13:38:39 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.zipkin2.ZipkinAutoConfiguration$RefreshScopedProbabilityBasedSamplerConfiguration': no URL paths identified
2021-06-24 13:38:39 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'scopedTarget.defaultTraceSampler': no URL paths identified
2021-06-24 13:38:39 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'defaultTraceSampler': no URL paths identified
2021-06-24 13:38:39 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.zipkin2.sender.ZipkinRestTemplateSenderConfiguration$DiscoveryClientZipkinUrlExtractorConfiguration$ZipkinClientLoadBalancedConfiguration': no URL paths identified
2021-06-24 13:38:39 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'loadBalancerClientZipkinLoadBalancer': no URL paths identified
2021-06-24 13:38:39 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.zipkin2.sender.ZipkinRestTemplateSenderConfiguration$DiscoveryClientZipkinUrlExtractorConfiguration': no URL paths identified
2021-06-24 13:38:39 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.zipkin2.sender.ZipkinRestTemplateSenderConfiguration': no URL paths identified
2021-06-24 13:38:39 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'restTemplateSender': no URL paths identified
2021-06-24 13:38:39 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'zipkinUrlExtractor': no URL paths identified
2021-06-24 13:38:39 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'spring.zipkin.sender-org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.zipkin2.sender.ZipkinSenderProperties': no URL paths identified
2021-06-24 13:38:39 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.zipkin2.ZipkinAutoConfiguration': no URL paths identified
2021-06-24 13:38:39 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'zipkinRestTemplateCustomizer': no URL paths identified
2021-06-24 13:38:39 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'sleuthReporterMetrics': no URL paths identified
2021-06-24 13:38:39 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'spring.zipkin-org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.zipkin2.ZipkinProperties': no URL paths identified
2021-06-24 13:38:39 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'spring.sleuth.sampler-org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.sampler.SamplerProperties': no URL paths identified
2021-06-24 13:38:39 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.log.SleuthLogAutoConfiguration$Slf4jConfiguration': no URL paths identified
2021-06-24 13:38:39 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.log.SleuthLogAutoConfiguration': no URL paths identified
2021-06-24 13:38:39 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.TraceAutoConfiguration': no URL paths identified
The following is what's in my pom and properties files

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <sonar.junit.reportsPath>target/surefire-reports</sonar.junit.reportsPath>
    <sonar.clover.reportPath>target/site/clover/clover.xml</sonar.clover.reportPath>
</properties>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    </dependency>  


spring.application.name=xxxx
spring.sleuth.sampler.percentage=100.0
spring.sleuth.enabled=true
spring.zipkin.baseUrl=http://dev.zipkin.cloud.xxxxxx.com:9411/      
spring.zipkin.sender.type=web
endpoints.enabled=true

logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.sleuth=DEBUG
```

Comment: Please try to upgrade to one of these versions since what you are using is not supported anymore:
2020.0.x aka Ilford -> 2.4.x, 2.5.x (Starting with 2020.0.3)
Hoxton -> 2.2.x, 2.3.x (Starting with SR5)

Answer (score 0):

You're using ancient versions of Spring Boot and Spring Cloud. Please upgrade to the latest version. You can go to start.spring.io and generate a project that uses Boot and Sleuth.